# How to adjust lines length in dendrogram?

Tags: r, dendextend

Using this code in R,

```
library("dendextend")
library("dendextendRcpp")

dist2 <- read.csv("distanceMatrix.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE)
mat <- as.matrix(dist2)

# using piping to get the dend
dend <- dist2 %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>% set("labels", colnames(mat))


foo <- function(k){
svg(filename = "dendrogram_newest.svg",width = 25,height = 14)
# plot + color the dend's branches before, based on k clusters:
dend %>% color_branches(k) %>% plot()
# add horiz line:
abline(h = heights_per_k.dendrogram(dend)[k], lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = "purple")
dev.off()}

foo(6)
```

I get this:

[image]

So, how to shorten these lines. This way is almost unreadable.

And yes, my labels are ordered just like in first row of my distanceMatrix.csv. This order has nothing to do with relations inside of distanceMatrix. I mean, dendrogram is ok but values of labels aren't the right one.

Thanks

Comment: @RichardScriven Seems like it'd make it a lot easier to identify sets of labels that all belong to a particular group. (That said, in some dendrograms, branch length is itself meaningful. If this is one of those, the OP will of course need to clearly indicate to viewers that they've shortened all of the terminal branches.)